# Matter-enabled Hue bridge: Chip-tool setup/pin code?

Tags: matter-iot-standard

I want to pair (commision) my Matter-enabled Hue bridge using Chip-tool.

The app pairing code is different from the setup/pin code I need: The former is a decimal figure with 11 digits (e.g. 0373-813-7401), while the latter is a 27-bit value (e.g. 20202021, in decimal notation). I have yet to figure out if there is any relation.

I tried commisioning my Hue bridge with

`chip-tool pairing onnetwork <node_id> <pin_code>`

where pin code was 20202021 (the developer default), but that didnt work:

`CHIP:SC: Failed to verify peer's MAC. This can happen when setup code is incorrect.`

So, which code should I use?

Comment: Hi, for 11 digits, you'll need : chip-tool pairing code 0x11 02000407704 . The 11 digit code you mentioned above is not equal to pin code.